# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why this code giving error?

```
def checkfermat(a,b,c,n) :
    if (a**n+b**n)!=c**n :
      print "fermat is absolutely correct.."
    else :
      print "he is wrong"
a=raw_input("enter the first number")
b=raw_input("enter the second num")
c=raw_input("enter the third num")
d=raw_input("enter the fourth num")
checkfermat(a,b,c,d)
```

With out the user input section it is showing no errors?

Comment: can you provide me the solution?

Comment: use `a = int(a)`
or you can even do `a = int(raw_input("enter the first number"))`

Comment: thanks a lot bro :)